# Call Forwarding Error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i want to call forwarding in this code:

```
    NSString *phone =@"**21*08150815#";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but not working.What is the problem? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a "//" after the ":"

```
NSString *phone =@"**21*08150815#"; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",phone]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: No. [`tel:` urls](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) don't need slashes. The problem is that iOS restricts the use of openURL to regular telephone numbers. You can't use service codes in them.

Comment: This code is not working.i used both technique but does not worked.i m using sdk 7.0 so service is not coming to output.i m taking in log all numbers truly but not executing.